# Correct file path img src, image not loading PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to echo out an image in a PHP function using 'img src', but I can't get it to work. The function itself works fine, everything else that I return or echo is working.

The image is located 1 folder 'back / up', then into the folder 'images' and the name of the image I'd like to acces in the 'images' folder is 'nike1.jpg'.

The following code isn't working:

```
echo '<img src="../images/nike1.jpg">';
```

No idea what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the image is located in backup then it should be echo '<img src="../backup/images/nike1.jpg">';

Comment: @YogeshPawar I think `back / up` refers to the parent directory.

Comment: write exact image path and your file path

Comment: you can check by putting the path like echo '<img src="/images/nike1.jpg">';

Comment: You can check in the network tab of your developer tools in the browser which path is being loaded instead.

Comment: `../` indicates the parent directory.. Check this page http://www.pagetutor.com/html_tutor/missing.html

Comment: Could you post your directory/file structure?

Comment: My file structure where the image nike1.jpg is located: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Brackets/Sneakerlab/images

The file structure of the php file 'item.php' that will load the image:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Brackets/Sneakerlab/pages

thanks for all the replies!

Comment: Just checked with inspect element -> console in chrome and now I'm sure I'm using the right path. I get the following messages in the console: GET http://localhost/Brackets/Sneakerlab/images/nike1.jpg 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 1):

Its because your image files don't have proper read permission, make sure those image files are readable.If you are an Linux user type the bellow command which will provide all access to the file.

First go to the image file directory in terminal and type the following.

```
sudo chmod 777 *
```

Comment: read permissions may be the problem, but I am hard pressed to think of the situation in which you can justify giving full access to a directory for everyone. That is a crazy security issue even in a supposedly image only directory (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-inject-executable-malicious-code-into-pdf-jpeg-mp3-etc). just do it right and set reasonable permissions for the account that is going to access the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your path. I am little confused that you have "back" and "up" as two different folders or its one folder. It should be like "/your_parent_directory/back/up/images/nike1.jpg" or you can also write as "../back/up/images/nike1.jpg" if back and up are two folders.
Can you tell the full path of the image.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant with 'back / up' is going on level 'back' in the file structure, hence the '../'

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, but I decided to upload the image(s) on imgur and just use the image URL. Thanks for all the support.